# How to prevent from transaction to close at the catch(Exception e)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, connection

I'm trying to run a query from java to PosgresSQL and I get an error from the `stmt.execute(sql)`

I would like to execute a new query to help me print out the specific row failing, but when I get to the  `catch (Exception e)` the transaction is aborted.

I cant create a new transaction because I'm working with temp tables. How do I prevent the transaction to abort?

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

```
try (Statement stmt = data.db.getConnection().createStatement()) {
        //  data.db.getConnection().setSavepoint("sp01");
        // insert to fact table
        TableSchema factTableSchema = factInfo.getTableSchema();
        // build SQL
        String sql = "Select * From....";
        try {
            stmt.execute(sql); // this row is failing 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
         // now i would like to run a query   only in case arrived here, but the transaction is closed
                      // how could i prevent from trasanction to close ?
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(" SELECT Bla,Bla From..");
                Log.debug("");
            }
            catch (Exception e2) {
                Log.debug("");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a new Statement.

Comment: What exception do you get, because a `select` would usually not result in an exception unless you have a syntax error. Note that PostgreSQL aborts transactions on errors and there is no recovery except starting a new transaction.

Comment: The first exception is integer out of range.

Comment: Avoid it by using correct sql? Because that's exactly what I would expect from a transaction. Abort and rollback on failure ...

Comment: @Fildor That is a matter of taste, some people (and a number of database systems) leave transaction commit or rollback after error up to the program (for example when some corrective action can be taken).

Comment: do you have connection.setAutoCommit(false) because it works fine for me the transactoin is not closed until i say so

Comment: @achabahe didn't make any different

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: i am using mysql and i dont even write setAutoCommit(false) the transaction continues until i close the connection and the temporary table remains visible to me I am going to try what you have said in postgres and see what happens

Comment: Francy what you are saying is not compatible with the documentation because temporary tables will remain the as long as the session is open with the database you can change this behavior by add ON COMMIT 'Action' in  the table creation statement but by default it will remain and the rows won't be deleted http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: can you give me the vesion you are working with

Comment: i have tried what you said in Postgres 9.3 and it works like in MYSQL no preblem

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's correct. But what I meant to say was that if I do not take any further measures, this is the default behavior I'd expect. Of course I have to admit, I did not know if OP has taken such measures.

Comment: @Fildor It is the default (and only) behavior of PostgreSQL as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new statement in the 2nd try block before you execute the query.

```
Statement stmt = data.db.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(" SELECT Bla,Bla From..");
```

`ResultSet` needs to be connected and alive to perform a `next();`

Comment: What do you have to commit in a query?

Comment: Even for queries you need transactions to get the right visibility guarantees. In JDBC you either have auto-commit, or you disable auto-commit and then the programmer decides the transaction end by explicitly calling commit or rollback.